# How to use Visual Studio's C# Windows Forms Design View for a Scalable/Resizable Window?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am attempting to create a Windows Forms Application that will have components that scale when the window is being resized. I am running into issues with the Form when attempting to resize it when the application is running. First of all, this is what it looks like in the editor at its Minimum Size:[image: in the design view]

Then I stretch it out at run time and it is even on both sides (after tinkering with the Fixed-Splitter position:[image: wider]

I run into more problems when attempting to put List Boxes in the blue and red panels. In design:[image: with list box]

Stretched:[image: with list box]

I want the list boxes to nicely fill most of the width of each side, but when I attempt to use the Anchor tags it gets messed up.

So to sum up: Why is the designer all asymmetrical compared to the finished product and how do I make the List Boxes fit and scale in width when the window is resized?

I am using VS17 if that helps! Thanks!

Comment: You need to adjust your anchors/docking for the controls, or use WPF/UWP which is designed to scale much more dynamically.

Comment: Yes, you will have to dock these items. Winforms are not very good at this but you can achieve by creating multiple panels and then docking the list boxes in them.

Comment: Thank you both! I don't understand the downvote(s) haha

Comment: @AmishJohn81 I didn't DV, it seems to be a theme around here to DV every new question that isn't above an "Advanced" level. Don't let it discourage you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anchors was always (I don't know why) littlebit broken. Use the composition of nested `Panel`s and use the `Dock` and `Padding` properties instead of anchros.